# How to manipulate react-day-picker to show next week

Tags: reactjs, typescript, date, progressive-web-apps

So i made a component where i only want to show the "week view", i managed to do it only for current week (per this url: [How to customize react-calendar to show only one week at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108844/how-to-customize-react-calendar-to-show-only-one-week-at-a-time)):

```
"use client"

import {
    endOfWeek,
    isWithinInterval,
    startOfWeek,
} from "date-fns";

import {
    DayPicker,
    Row,
    RowProps,
} from "react-day-picker";

import "react-day-picker/dist/style.css";

function CurrentWeekRow(props: RowProps) {
    const isDateInCurrentWeek = (dateToCheck: Date) => {
        const today = new Date()
        const start = startOfWeek(today);
        const end = endOfWeek(today);
        return isWithinInterval(dateToCheck, { start, end });
    };
    const isNotCurrentWeek = props.dates.every((date) => !isDateInCurrentWeek(date));
    if (isNotCurrentWeek) return <></>;
    return <Row {...props} />;
}

const DateComponent = () => {

    return (

        <div>
            <div>
                <DayPicker
                    components={{ Row: CurrentWeekRow }}
                    showOutsideDays
                    mode="single"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DateComponent;
```

What renders is current week and upon clicking on next button or previous button it shows nothing as per pictures.

CURRENT WEEK:

[image]

UPON CLICKING NEXT BUTTON:

[image]

So yea that is basicly what I need help with manipulating the react-day-picker or maybe using some other library for this functionality. I need this week "switching" and upon clicking on a day saving date to a state. How to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the solution with react-day-picker and made my own with date-fns library

```
const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());
const [currentWeek, setCurrentWeek] = useState<Array<Date>>([]);
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<Date>(new Date());

const getCurrentWeek = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    const start = startOfWeek(today, { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    const end = endOfWeek(today, { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    setCurrentWeek(eachDayOfInterval({ start: start, end: end }))
};

const getNextWeek = () => {
    const end = endOfWeek(currentDate, { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    const nextWeekStart = startOfWeek(new Date(end.getTime() + 1), { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    const nextWeekEnd = endOfWeek(new Date(end.getTime() + 7), { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    setCurrentWeek(eachDayOfInterval({ start: nextWeekStart, end: nextWeekEnd }))
    setCurrentDate(new Date(end.getTime() + 1));
};

const getPreviousWeek = () => {
    const start = startOfWeek(currentDate, { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    const previousWeekStart = startOfWeek(new Date(start.getTime() - 1), { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    const previousWeekEnd = endOfWeek(new Date(start.getTime() - 7), { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    setCurrentWeek(eachDayOfInterval({ start: previousWeekStart, end: previousWeekEnd }))
    setCurrentDate(new Date(start.getTime() - 1));
};

useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentWeek()
}, [])
```

This now renders weekly wiew with buttons to switch weeks to next and previous:

[image]

```
     <div>
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <span style={{ marginBottom: "20px", fontSize: "20px" }}>{format(currentDate, "MMMM")}</span>
            <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 justify-center items-center">
                <ArrowCircleLeftOutlinedIcon onClick={() => getPreviousWeek()} style={{ height: "45px", width: "45px", color: "#68d6c0", fontSize: "16px", fontWeight: "bold", borderRadius: "50%" }} />
                {currentWeek.map((date) => (
                    <DayDateItem item={date} selected={selected} setSelected={setSelected} />
                ))}
                <ArrowCircleRightOutlinedIcon onClick={() => getNextWeek()} style={{ height: "45px", width: "45px", color: "#68d6c0", fontSize: "16px", fontWeight: "bold", borderRadius: "50%" }} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```